# Meaning of \\1 in madlib.gsub!(/\(\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\)/, "<%= q_to_a('\\1') %>")

Tags: ruby, parameters

I am trying to understand the following code [from Ruby Quiz website](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz28.html).

I don't get the `'\\1'` part in `madlib.gsub!(/\(\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\)/, "<%= q_to_a('\\1') %>")` which is the third line from the bottom.

Is `'\\1'` escaping? Where does `1` come from?

I thank you in advance.

This is the whole code.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby -w
#---
# Excerpted from "Best of Ruby Quiz"
# We make no guarantees that this code is fit for any purpose. 
# Visit http://www.pragmaticprogrammer.com/titles/fr_quiz for more book information.
#---

# use Ruby's standard template engine
require "erb"

# storage for keyed question reuse
$answers = Hash.new

# asks a madlib question and returns an answer
def q_to_a( question )
  question.gsub!(/\s+/, " ")       # normalize spacing

  if $answers.include? question    # keyed question
    $answers[question]
  else                             # new question
    key = if question.sub!(/^\s*(.+?)\s*:\s*/, "") then $1 else nil end

    print "Give me #{question}:  "
    answer = $stdin.gets.chomp

    $answers[key] = answer unless key.nil?

    answer
  end
end

# usage
unless ARGV.size == 1 and test(?e, ARGV[0])
  puts "Usage:  #{File.basename($PROGRAM_NAME)} MADLIB_FILE"
  exit  
end

# load Madlib, with title
madlib = "\n#{File.basename(ARGV.first, '.madlib').tr('_', ' ')}\n\n" +
         File.read(ARGV.first)
# convert ((...)) to <%= q_to_a('...') %>
madlib.gsub!(/\(\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\)/, "<%= q_to_a('\\1') %>")
# run template
ERB.new(madlib).run
```

Comment: from this `(.+?)` part of `Regexp`. The `\1`, `\2`, etc get a value from consequently standing parentheses, as well as `$1`, `$2`, etc when no `:gsub` is used.

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you were looking for a string that contained two identical words separated by a white space. You might begin by writing `(.+?)\s`, but you would need some way to represent the same content that the first set of parentheses was matched to. This is exactly what `\n` (or `\\n`) does. It refers to the content of the nth set of parentheses. So if you wanted to extract the `"ef ef"` from `"ab cd ef ef gh ik"` you could use the following regex expression

```
(.+?)\s\1
```

In your particular case, as other have pointed out, the `\\1` refers specifically to the content of `(.+?)`. Note that all the other parentheses are preceded by escape characters to match to actual parentheses in the text and so they are not taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

That means the first matched group on your regex or this block `(.+?)`.

Take a look at this to help your understading: http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Answer (score 0):

`1` comes from this `(.+?)` part of `Regexp`. The `\1`, `\2`, etc get a value from consequently standing parentheses, as well as `$1`, `$2`, etc, when no `:gsub` or other method with block or replacement is used.